# stylePreprocessorOptions is not working for test

Tags: angular-cli

I have a problem with the includePath for stylePreprocessorOptions, whatever I do it doesn't work.

I have seen that there are solved tickets on github but I am running out of options, any idea might help :-). Any source I have found suggests to add the option I have already added.

```
Error message:

ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

@import 'variables';
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: variables.
      in /home/rdeutz/projects/rbt/checkout-system-v3/src/app/app.component.scss (line 1, column 1)
Error: 
@import 'variables';
```

Here is my configuration:

```
 {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my1": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-my1",
            "index": "src/index-my1.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/my1"
              ]
            },
    ....

        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/my1/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": [
                  "src/my1"
                ]
            }
          }
        },
```

All is good for build but tests are not working.

```
Versions:

Angular CLI: 7.2.3
Node: 10.15.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 7.2.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.12.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.12.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.12.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.12.3
@angular-devkit/core              7.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.2.3
@angular/cli                      7.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  7.2.3
@schematics/angular               7.2.3
@schematics/update                0.12.3
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.28.4

npm --version -> 6.4.1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Was a more or less stupid mistake. Two projects were configured and it run through for one but not for the other one. So the error came from the 2nd run and the 2nd one was properly configured.